# How to convert an array of webp to a webm

Tags: javascript, webm, webp

I am successfully creating an array of webp files using the following javascript from a video that is being copied to a canvas

```
frames.push=canvas.toDataUrl('image/webp');
```

Now that I have an array of webp, I want to create a webm video from the array and post the webm video to my server.  Can this be done with javascript?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. Your essentially asking if a (assumed by me) browser can encode a video out of your images.

Comment: @nietonfir It is possible, I just want to see if there is an way to do it with html5 instead of whammy - http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/31486670538/creating-webm-video-from-getusermedia

Comment: Interesting. Well, you should rephrase your question then (something along the lines mentioning HTML5 and mediastream recording imho), because it is obviously possible with javascript via [whammy](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy). ;-)